# "copy artifacts from another project" from mulijob to multiconfiguration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a multijob project with few multi-configuration jobs as "multiJob phase":

```
JobMaster (multijob)
   MultiJobPhase
      name: Build
          job: CentosJob(multiconfiguration), (axis: i686 and x86)
          job: UbuntuJob(multiconfiguration), (axis: i686 and x86)
```

JobMaster runs periodically and starts at first CentosJob and then UbuntuJob one by one. CentosJob and UbuntuJob generate some artifacts. I want to copy these artifacts to JobMaster. I tried to use "Copy artifacts from another project" plugin but couldn't understand its settings. Their  names seems to be very confusing. Please clarify if it's possible and how to achieve that.